# Connected to Pluggable Database - Cannot See Any Tables - SQL*PLUS

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, plsqldeveloper, pluggable-database

I am using *sqlplus* to connect to a pluggable database that is running on my localhost. However, when I connect I cannot see any of the tables from the major schemas.

Does anyone know how to trouble shoot this type of problem? When I connect using PL/SQL Developer however I am able to see the tables. I am connecting to the pluggable database using sql*plus like so: 
`sqlplus localhost:1521/services.domain as sysdba`

When I try to select a table I see an error that the table or view does not exist. When I connect with PL/SQL developer like so, shown below in Figure 1, I do not have the problem of not being able to select any tables.

[image]

Figure 1: Logging into PL/SQL Developer

Comment: I'd rather see the SQL*Plus screenshot instead of login PL/SQL Developer screen. What do you do? Which command did you run? Logged as SYSTEM, you have access to all tables, but you have to precede their names with their owner names. Would that help?

Comment: The resident PL/SQL expert helped me out at the office. I was connecting to an outer container the containter database (CBD) and not the pluggable database (PDB). There was a slight problem with the syntax of my sql*plus log-in string that was logging in as sysdba to the CBD and not as the system user to the PDB.